# Electrostatics: Is conductor charge 0 only in isolated conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, conductors

I'm having a little bit of confusion in electrostatic analysis of conductors.
Is the total charge $Q$ enclosed in a conductor equal to zero in **isolated** conductors? If we are applying a voltage $Vo$ between ground and a conductor this conductor will be at a potential $Vo$ does that allow the presence of charges in the conductor now?

Source of confusion : If in conductors $Q=0$ then why does $Q=\int_a^b \epsilon \vec E. d\vec S \neq 0  $ in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

If by “enclosed” you mean totally enclosed, yes, it’s zero always, isolated or not.

Formally, draw an (arbitrary) surface totally inside the conductor that encloses wherever you’re interested in. The field everywhere on this surface is zero (it’s a conductor) so the E field flux through it is also zero, so by Gaus’s law the enclosed charge is zero.

Operationally, charge will move around inside the conductor until this is so. I.e. if you place an extra charge Q in a void, it will attract -Q to neutralize.

Answer (score 0):

stackexchange.com/users/183314/thedatascientist101

In isolated conductors, the total charge Qenclosed may not necessarily be equal to zero. However, the net charge on an isolated conductor must be zero. This means that the conductor has equal amounts of positive and negative charge, which cancel each other out, resulting in a net charge of zero.

In electrostatics, it is important to differentiate between isolated conductors and conductors that are connected to a voltage source or other conductors. When a conductor is connected to a voltage source, it may acquire a net charge as a result of the voltage difference between the conductor and the voltage source.

In the absence of an external voltage source, the net charge on an isolated conductor is determined by the distribution of charges on its surface. In electrostatic equilibrium, the electric field inside a conductor is zero, which means that any excess charge on the conductor will distribute itself uniformly on the surface.

Therefore, in an isolated conductor, the total charge Qenclosed may not be zero, but the net charge on the conductor must be zero.

Now let me explain your second question...
Yes, applying a voltage Vo between ground and a conductor will cause the conductor to be at a potential of Vo relative to ground. This potential difference will create an electric field between the conductor and ground, which can cause charges to flow into or out of the conductor depending on the polarity of the voltage.

If the voltage is positive with respect to ground, the potential of the conductor will be higher than the potential of ground, and electrons will tend to flow from ground to the conductor to neutralize the potential difference. This will result in an excess of negative charge on the conductor.

Conversely, if the voltage is negative with respect to ground, the potential of the conductor will be lower than the potential of ground, and electrons will tend to flow from the conductor to ground to neutralize the potential difference. This will result in a deficit of negative charge on the conductor, or an excess of positive charge.

Therefore, applying a voltage between ground and a conductor can lead to the presence of charges in the conductor, depending on the polarity of the voltage and the initial charge distribution of the conductor.

T think now ou are clear with your question....